# NXT screen either flickering or blank, what do I do?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, repair

The screen on my LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT brick has just stopped working. It is either flickering, or blank. I have tried turning it on and off, installed fresh batteries, and I can even hear the selection sounds. Additionally, it responds regularly when I connect it to my computer. I've had my NXT for three-and-a-half years, so it's not new. Is there an easy/feasible way to fix it, or a cheap way to get it replaced?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the two easiest options:

1. **Replace it.** [Contact LEGO](http://service.lego.com/en-US/default.aspx), and tell them of your problem. I've
   hear many success stories from people who did this, and LEGO
   replacing it for free. For one person, it took a week to arrive, but
   for another, three days. Note that if you want to keep your old NXT,
   you'll have to have the receipt. If you don't have the receipt, then
   you'll have to send them your deffective NXT. Also, if you did not
   buy your NXT directly from LEGO, (i.e. Ebay) they will not replace
   it for free, but rather ask that you pay them to repair it.
2. **Repair it.** If you have a soldering kit, then get it out, and follow
   the instructions in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCZNc7tPop0). It worked for me the first try.

Comment: I would recommend option 2 first. LEGO does have a nice customer serviec and they'll probably replace it without discussion. However, they want want to ask for the faulty part to be returned, and if it has be tinkered with, they may not be super happy about it. Keep the soldering iron for when LEGO absolutely doesn't want to replace it (never).

Comment: I disagree. Mine recently gave out when I was right in the middle of making a robot. I wanted to get back to building my robot as soon as possible, so I soldered it. It only took about ten to fifteen minutes to heat it up the soldering iron, disassemble the NXT, solder the capacitors, slightly reassemble it the NXT, test it, and finish reassembling it. It's really not that risky if you know what you're doing. I much prefer soldering it over having to wait a week or so.

Comment: As you said, "if you know what you're doing" (I sure wouldn't). Wait... you've only got one? ;)

Comment: @Joubarc No, I have two NXTs. Sorry, I should've said "one of mine" Instead of "mine". And now I understand better what you're saying.

Comment: @HaydenStudios As Joubarc said, I would swap the two steps around, especially if your answer is to be valuable for future visitors to this question.

Comment: I tried this unfortunately without any success. After the first attempt the flickering lines disappeared and the screen was all dead. I gave it another try, and the flickering came back!