# Does LEGO still exchange the Mindstorms NXT bricks with flicker problems?

Tags: nxt, repair

I'm new here. Does LEGO still exchange the Mindstorms NXT bricks with flicker problems? If not, does anyone know of someone willing to try and fix them for a fee or barter?

Comment: Have you seen http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/677/nxt-screen-either-flickering-or-blank-what-do-i-do?